# Using bitwise & operator and + in Java giving inconsistent results

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Could someone please explain why these two pieces of Java codes are behaving differently? First one correctly counts number of bits but the second one just displays 1 or 0 for non-zero numbers. I don't understand whats happening.

```
    public static void printNumUnitBits(int n){
    int num=0;
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
        int x=n&1;
        num=num+x;
        n=n>>>1;
        }
     System.out.println("Number of one bits:"+num);
    }

    public static void printNumUnitBits(int n){
    int num=0;
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
        num=num+n&1;
        n=n>>>1;
        }
     System.out.println("Number of one bits:"+num);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, `+` has [higher precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than `&`. Your expression `num+n&1` will add `num` and `n` and then take the lowest bit.

To fix this, try making the statement in the second example `num=num+(n&1);`.

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence. `+` has higher priority than `&`.  Your code

```
num=num+n&1
```

Will be executed like

```
num=(num+n)&1
```

Look [here](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php)

Answer (score 1):

[Operators precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

```
int x=n&1;
num=num+x;
```

and

```
num=num+n&1;
```

are different.
You're doing the bitwise & in a different moment.